# How do I move the head?

Tags: g-code, klipper, elegoo-neptune-4-pro

I have an Elegoo Neptune 4 Pro (love it), and I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi with a camera to take a photo every time a layer is complete (to build a time-lapse).

This means I'll have to edit the G-code to move the print head to the X-axis maximum to press a button (shutter release).

I'm using the web interface and would like to know how to get the X-axis position using G-code commands.

I've found [Klipper documentation: G-Codes](https://www.klipper3d.org/G-Codes.html) and have tried to run a few of the commands.

`M114` gives the following line:

`14:58:56 X:141.000 Y:98.000 Z:11.090 E:0.000`

However, when I try to send the print head to that location from somewhere else, I get errors.

```
$ G0 X:141.000 Y:98.000 Z:11.090 E:0.000
!! Unable to parse move 'G0 X:141.000 Y:98.000 Z:11.090 E:0.000'
$ G0 [X:141.000] [Y:98.000] [Z:11.090] [E:0.000]
// Unknown command:"G0 ["
$ G0 [141.000] [98.000] [11.090] [0.000]
// Unknown command:"G0 [141.000] [98.000] [11.090] [0.000]"
$ G0 141.000 98.000 11.090 E:0.000
// Unknown command:"G0 141.000 98.000 11.090"
$ G0 X:141.000 Y:98.000 Z:11.090 E:0.000
```

All of these tried with `G1` as well as `G0`

Based on the error messages, it looks like the first line above is the way to go; But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried sending `G0 X141.000 Y98.000 Z11.090 E0.000`?

Comment: `G1 X141 F5000` will send the head to X=141 without touching Y and Z, and do it *fast*. [also, while G0 and G1 can be used pretty much equally, it is "traditional" to use G0 for printing/cutting/work in general, G1 for free movement between work points.]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the commands are invalid due to improper syntax. The Klipper Documentation site does seem to be a bit confusing. The main list of G-codes can be found on the [RepRap wiki](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code).

The site provides the proper usage and examples:

> **Usage**
>
> ```
> G0 Xnnn Ynnn Znnn Ennn Fnnn Snnn 
> G1 Xnnn Ynnn Znnn Ennn Fnnn Snnn
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> G0 X12               ; move to 12mm on the X axis  
> G0 F1500             ; Set the feedrate to 1500mm/min  
> G1 X90.6 Y13.8 E22.4 ; Move to 90.6mm on the X axis and 13.8mm on the Y axis while extruding 22.4mm of material
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The provided link shows the correct syntax, the ":" character is not in the Klipper G-code specification and remember the "[" and "]" characters imply that the parameter is optional and "<" and ">" imply: "insert a value here".

From the documentation:

> Move (`G0` or `G1`): `G1 [X<pos>] [Y<pos>] [Z<pos>] [E<pos>] [F<speed>]`

A valid command would be:

`G0 X141.000 Y98.000 Z11.090 E0.000`<sup>1)</sup>

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Note that this is an example based on the provided G-code in the question, the use of the `E0.000` is not recommended, this can retract the filament all the way from the extruder based on the last position of `E`. If you want a move to a position, retract first (using a relative positioning of `E`), then move (using an absolute positioning of `X, Y, Z`), take a picture, move back and re-retract the same value (using a relative positioning of `E`).*